# how to avoid breaking a line in dmath mode?

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

I tried all 3 options above that I have seen recommended in other threads/answers, but none seem to work

```
\begin{dmath}
P (A>B \cap A>B+C)=P(A>B+C)=P(A=\nolinebreak 3 \cap B=\nolinebreak 1 \cap C=\nolinebreak 1)=\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{27}
\end{dmath}

\begin{dmath}
P (A>B \cap A>B+C)=P(A>B+C)=P(A=\nolinebreak3 \cap B=\nolinebreak 1 \cap C=\nolinebreak1)=\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{27}
\end{dmath}

\begin{dmath}
P (A>B \cap A>B+C)=P(A>B+C)=P(A\hiderel{=}3 \cap B\hiderel{=}\cap C\hiderel{=}1)=\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{27}
\end{dmath}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a pair of braces (`{}`) around the part that shouldn't break:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}
\begin{dmath}
P({A>B \cap A>B+C}) 
= P({A>B+C})
= P({A= 3 \cap B=1 \cap C=1})
=\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{3}
=\frac{1}{27}
\end{dmath}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which shows the shortcomings of `breqn`. *I* want to decide where to break my equations.

Answer (score 0):

Althought it is not said in your question, neither exposed in the MWE, I suppose you are using the [`breqn`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/breqn) package since it provides the `dmath` environment. This environment specifically breaks the equations, since it is meant to do so:

> 'breqn - Automatic line breaking of displayed equations (...) The sin­gle most am­bi­tious goal of the pack­age, how­ever, is to sup­port au­to­matic line­break­ing of dis­played equa­tions'.

Using another equation environment will solve it:

```
\[
P (A>B \cap A>B+C)=P(A>B+C)=P(A=\nolinebreak 3 \cap B=\nolinebreak 1 \cap C=\nolinebreak 1)=\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{27}
\]

\begin{equation}
P (A>B \cap A>B+C)=P(A>B+C)=P(A=\nolinebreak3 \cap B=\nolinebreak 1 \cap C=\nolinebreak1)=\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{27}
%label{eq:myeq} %optional
\end{equation}

\begin{dmath}
P (A>B \cap A>B+C)=P(A>B+C)=P(A\hiderel{=}3 \cap B\hiderel{=}\cap C\hiderel{=}1)=\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{27}
\end{dmath}
```

With `\[` and `\]` you get numberless equations, and with the `equation` you get them numbered.

Since you equation is quite wide, you may want to display it in two lines, to have the numbering correctly set at the right:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
P (A>B \cap A>B+C) & = P(A>B+C)\\
& = P(A=\nolinebreak3 \cap B=\nolinebreak 1 \cap C=\nolinebreak1) = \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{27}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Thank you for you response. The reason why I like dmath is because it is breaking equations pretty nicely automatically, so I don't have to do a manual approach :(

Comment: `array` switches to `\textstyle`, and the spacing around the `=` is wrong, use `aligned` from `amsmath`.